# iOS8 extension unable to use AFNetworking library

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2, ios8-extension

> I am unable to use AFNetworking library in my app extension due to
>   that was trying to access the UIApplication class methods. Does any
>   one knows here any other better network library that does not access
>   UIApplication class?. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

quote from  [Guard for unsupported features of iOS 8 extensions #2589](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2589)

> To fix this issue i had to put AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1 as a preprocessor
>   macro for the Pods-hitta.se WatchKit Extension-AFNetworking target.
>   Adding #define AF_APP_EXTENSIONS to the prefix header didn't work,
>   neither did adding it as a preprocessor macro to the watch extension
>   target work.

So click on Pods project in Project Navigator, then select Pods-{your-app-name-extension}-AFNetworking. Next go to *Build Settings* and find *Preproccessor Macros* where you add new line with "AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1"

Also wrap it with *+#if !defined(AF_APP_EXTENSIONS)* at beginning. And end it *+#endif*

full example of wrapping:

```
- (void)updateNetworkActivityIndicatorVisibility {
+#if !defined(AF_APP_EXTENSIONS)
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:[self isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible]];
+#endif
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use AFNetworking with extension. You just need follow the instruction below.

> When using AFNetworking in an App Extension, #define AF_APP_EXTENSIONS
>   to avoid using unavailable APIs.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2119

Comment: Where do you place the macro??

Comment: This answer make no sense. Where to define this macro? How to use this macro? And how to import AFNetworking.h?